# Optic for partial conversion on both sides

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

`Prism` is like `Iso` except one of the two conversions is partial. Is there an optic where both conversions are partial?

Of course one can create a type `(s -> Maybe a, b -> Maybe t)` but I'm wondering if such a thing could be expressed an as [`Optic _ _`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Optic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution in `lens`-style optics (rather than profunctor optics as in the other answers) using the [`Filterable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.3.5/docs/Data-Witherable.html#t:Filterable) type-class:

```
-- A partial variant of (#) for partial reviews
infixr 8 #?
(#?) :: Optic Tagged Maybe s t a b -> b -> Maybe t
f #? b = Just b & Tagged & f & unTagged

-- A Prism "turned around", i.e a getter but a partial review
type InvPrism s t a b =
    forall p f. (Profunctor p, Filterable f) => Optic p f s t a b

-- A partial iso-morphism, i.e a partial getter and partial review
type PartialIso s t a b =
    forall p f. (Choice p, Applicative f, Filterable f) => Optic p f s t a b

-- Turn APrism around
invPrism :: APrism b a t s -> InvPrism s t a b
invPrism p =
    dimap
    (review (reviewing (clonePrism p)))
    (mapMaybe (^? getting (clonePrism p)))

-- Create a PartialIso from two partial conversions
partialIso :: (s -> Maybe a) -> (b -> Maybe t) -> PartialIso s t a b
partialIso sma ams =
    dimap
    (maybe (Left ()) Right . sma)
    (catMaybes . either (const (pure Nothing)) (fmap ams)) .
    right'

-- Coerce APrism to an Optic'
reviewing ::
    (Choice p, Bifunctor p, Functor f, Settable f) =>
    APrism s t a b -> Optic' p f t b
reviewing p =
    bimap f (fmap f)
    where
        f = runIdentity . unTagged . clonePrism p . Tagged . Identity
```

Comment: Your `Fallback` looks an awful lot like `Data.Witherable.Filterable`. Is there a reason not to use that here?

Comment: @dfeuer Now that you brought it to my attention I'll use it, thanks! I tried finding something like it but my google and hoogle skills might be lacking

Answer (score 4):

You can generalize `Iso`s (i.e., `(s -> a, b -> t)`) into `(s -> m a, b -> m t)` by replacing profunctors over Hask (i.e., `Profunctor`, that's the constraint in the definition of `Iso` as an `Optic`) with profunctors over Kleisli categories (here for the `Maybe` monad).

```
class Monad m => KProfunctor m p where
  dimapM :: (s -> m a) -> (b -> m t) -> p a b -> p s t

-- dimapM pure pure = id
-- dimapM f g . dimapM h i = dimapM (h >=> f) (g >=> i)

type Optic p s t a b = p a b -> p s t
type KIso m s t a b = forall p. KProfunctor m p => Optic p s t a b
```

To construct one example of such profunctor, take the type of pseudo-isos `(s -> m a, b -> m t)` that we are trying to work with in the first place, and put `s` and `t` as the main indices:

```
data PseudoIso m a b s t = MkPseudoIso
  { toM :: s -> m a
  , fromM :: b -> m t
  }

instance Monad m => KProfunctor m (PseudoIso m) where
  -- exercise for the reader
```

- To go from `PseudoIso` to `KIso`, use `dimapM` (the fields of `PseudoIso` are exactly the right type for the arguments of `dimapM`)
- To go from `KIso` to `PseudoIso`, partially apply to the identity `PseudoIso a b a b`

Actually, it doesn't have to be a Kleisli category. A profunctor over any category `(:->) :: k -> k -> Type` will give you a class of optics of the form `(s :-> a, b :-> t)`.

Note: you can define an instance of `Choice` with `KProfunctor Maybe`, so maybe everything should really be specialized to `Maybe` so `Choice` could reasonably be added as a superclass of `KProfunctor`, then `KIso` would be a subtype of `Prism`.

Comment: Interesting, but **a)** could this actually be used in a Van Laarhoven setting? **b)** is that really necessary, profunctors over a Kleisli category? Seems we're going a bit far with the abstractions.

Comment: **a)** VL lenses already don't generalize to prisms and isos; the lens library tries hard to keep the types compatible, but it really is using profunctor optics by the point you're talking about the `Optic` synonym  **b)** If you take what I said and set `m = Maybe`, then you get exactly what the question needs. It doesn't require any additional work beyond that one substitution to fit the abstraction to the problem, so as far as abstractions go, I would argue this one is pretty tame.

Comment: Now it does seem that the special case of `Maybe` is important to see `KIso` as a subtype of `Prism`, so you have a point.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia What do you mean by "it really is using profunctor optics"? Doesn't `lens` have the extra `f` parameter there?

Comment: The `f` has little relevance when you're quantifying over `p`. You can do the same operations on `p a (f b)` for some abstract profunctor `p` and functor `f`, as on `q a b` for some abstract profunctor `q` (i.e., to construct an `Iso`). The constraints on `p` and `f` may be different from those on `q` as you go down the optic hierarchy, but they can be translated back and forth (at the very least by just decomposing `q` back into `p` and `f`).

Answer (score 3):

Let us look at profunctor encoding. It's simpler.

`Choice` is a class for `Prism`s, we are making subclass of `Prisms`, so `Choice` is natural choice for a superclass:

```hs
class Choice p => Weird p where
    weird :: (s -> Maybe a) -> (b -> Maybe t) -> p a b -> p s t
```

If we try to write an instance for `p = (->)`, it won't work.
So our new kind of optics is not a superclass of `Setter`.

The hierarchy would probably look something like: at best probably something like
(Can a `Traversal` and thus `Lens` be turned into the new `Weird` optic, maybe?)

```
     Lens
   /     \
Iso       Traversal -> Setter
   \      /
     Prism
         \ 
           Weird
```

---

Let's try with another concrete `Profunctor`s.
I'll use types as defined in [my blog post: Glassery](https://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-18-glassery.html)

`ForgetM` is used to implement `preview`

```hs
type Optic' p s a = p a a -> p s s

preview :: Optic' (ForgetM a) s a -> s -> Maybe a
preview o = runForgetM (o (ForgetM Just))

newtype ForgetM r a b = ForgetM { runForgetM :: a -> Maybe r }

instance Profunctor (ForgetM r) where
    dimap f _ (ForgetM p) = ForgetM (p . f)

instance Choice (ForgetM r) where
    right' (ForgetM p) = ForgetM (either (const Nothing) p)

instance Weird (ForgetM r) where
    weird sa _bt (ForgetM ab) = ForgetM $ \s -> sa s >>= ab
```

`TaggedM` can be used to define something in oppisite direction (not in `Glassery`):

```hs
repreview :: Optic' TaggedM s a -> a -> Maybe s
repreview o a = unTaggedM (o (TaggedM (Just a)))

newtype TaggedM a b = TaggedM { unTaggedM :: Maybe b }

instance Profunctor TaggedM where
    dimap _sa bt (TaggedM b) = TaggedM (fmap bt b)

instance Choice TaggedM where
    right' (TaggedM b) = TaggedM (fmap Right b)

instance Weird TaggedM where
    weird _sa bt (TaggedM b) = TaggedM (b >>= bt)
```

We can now try this.

Simple case works:

```hs
*Main> preview (weird Just Just) 'x'
Just 'x'
*Main> repreview (weird Just Just) 'x'
Just 'x'
```

Prisms can be used as new thing (thing `right' = _Right`):

```hs
*Main> preview right' (Left 'x')
Nothing
*Main> preview right' (Right 'x')
Just 'x'
```

---

There's also a nice symmetric `Profunctor`:

```hs
newtype Re p s t a b = Re { runRe :: p b a -> p t s }

instance Profunctor p => Profunctor (Re p s t) where
    dimap f g (Re p) = Re (p . dimap g f)

instance Cochoice p => Choice (Re p s t) where
    right' (Re p) = Re (p . unright)

instance Choice p => Cochoice (Re p s t) where
    unright (Re p) = Re (p . right')
```

and we can write `Weird` instance for it:

```hs
instance Weird p => Weird (Re p s t) where
    weird sa bt (Re p) = Re (p . weird bt sa)
```

And we notice that, we need to add `Cochoice` to be the superclass of `Weird`:

```hs
class (Choice p, Cochoice p) => Weird p where
    weird :: (s -> Maybe a) -> (b -> Maybe t) -> p a b -> p s t
```

That starts to look promising.

---

van-Laarhoven. That's tricky.

Compare `Prism` in profunctor and VL encodings:

```hs
type PrismVL s t a b = forall f p. (Choice p, Applicative f) => p a (f b) -> p s (f t)
type PrismP  s t a b = forall   p. (Choice p)                => p a    b  -> p s    t
```

The good start is to assume that this `Weird` thing would look like

```hs
type WeirdOptic s t a b = forall p f. (Weird p, Applicative f) => Optic p f s t a b
```

Maybe we would need to strengten the `f` constraint too, a bit.

But I leave something for you to experiment with.
Also an open question is what's the intuition behind this new `Weird` optic;
and what laws it should have (to be an optic, and not just two functions
smashed together). It feels than trying to do similar `Monad` / `Kleisli` optic
with anything fancier than `Maybe` is difficult, but maybe it would work out too.